# Subscript, Superscript, and Bracket

Tags: brackets, subscripts, superscripts

I want to write like this:
[image]

But when I write

> \documentclass{article} \usepackage{mathtools} \begin{document}
> \begin{equation}
> \lim\limits_{\Delta\rightarrow0}\Delta{}_{t=0}^{t=T}\left\vert\dfrac{df(t)}{dt}\right\vert^2
> dt    \end{equation} \end{document}

The output was like this
[image]

Anyone can tell me what is my mistake?

Comment: As always on this site please post a full minimal example, not just a sniplet like this. Please post something others can copy and test as is without adding anything

Comment: Use this ``\lim\limits_{\Delta\to 0}\; \Delta_{t=0}^{t=T}\;\left| \dfrac{d\,f(t)}{dt} \right|^2\; dt``

Comment: @daleif thank you, I've edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_{t=0}^{t=T}` in your line makes these things the superscript and subscript of the `\lim\limits_{\Delta\rightarrow0}{}`. I would do it using `\prescript` from `mathtools` package.

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
```

and then in the math environment:

```
\lim\limits_{\Delta\rightarrow0}{} \Delta\prescript{t=T}{t=0}{\left\vert\dfrac{df(t)}{dt}\right\vert^2 dt}
```

This provides the result as follows:[image]

Comment: The upper prescript is higher than necessary.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to modify it using this method.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have used `\lower` command. See my update 1.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an attempt to faithfully reproduce the first screenshot you posted.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional
\begin{document}
\[
\lim_{\Delta\phantom{\to}0} \Delta
\begin{array}{>{\scriptstyle}l@{}} t=T \\ t=0 \end{array}
\Bigl| \frac{df\!(t)}{dt} \Bigr|^2 dt
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I feel the original image posted is missing `tends to` in the limits. It's a strange equation as it means nothing.

Comment: @Tanvir - The OP stated that he/she wanted to reproduce the first image. The code in my answer achieves that.

Comment: @Tanvir yes, you're right. there is something missing and a strange equation, because the source file that I used has incomplete equation.

Comment: @Mico thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using...`tensor` package.....with the enviroment `mathtools`...an alternative a bit more complicated :-)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}
\[\lim_{\Delta\phantom{\to}0} \Delta \tensor*[^T_t]{\bigg\lvert \frac{df(t)}{dt}\bigg\rvert}{^2} dt\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Update 1

Using `\lower-0.01em` with `\hbox` and `\scriptstyle` it is possible a nice alignment between `T` and `2`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}
\[\lim_{\Delta\to 0} \Delta \tensor*[^{\lower-0.01em \hbox{$\scriptstyle T$}}_t]{\bigg\lvert \frac{df(t)}{dt}\bigg\rvert}{^2} dt\]
\end{document}
```

[image]